# Dog whining digging garden

Tags: dogs, behavior

**Details of the dog:**

Female Yellow Labrador, 3 years old, gets vaccination on time.

**I would request answer to following behavior of my dog and any treatment for this:**

Whining when entering room, smelling the floor and trying to dig the tiles.
Digging garden soil. This started about 10 days ago.

**A few things which happened:**

About 15 days ago I moved to a hostel and my dog is now at home with my other family members. She obtained a toy duck from somewhere and is keeping it safe in her kennel.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dogs dig for a few reasons: 
1: To hunt ground animals 
2: To bury something they want to use later
3: To form a cool spot to lay in
4: Separation anxiety

You mentioned that you have recently moved somewhere and the dog remained behind? Your dog may be feeling separation anxiety, just like people when dogs are anxious they develop bad habits. Some people chew on their finger nails or crack their knuckles repeatedly, likewise dogs will Dig obsessively, whine, bark, howl, or chew up furniture when stressed or anxious.

Comment: Thank you, I think it was separation anxiety (as you mentioned) ;now she is back to her normal behavior.

Comment: Happy to help! Our dog did the same stuff when I got a job with different working hours

Answer (score 1):

We have a 2 year old female Labrador.

She incessantly searches for moles in our backyard when they are most active during the spring, summer and fall seasons.

In fact, she is outside **right now** digging into a moles mound.

Most of the time, she will dig up the mounds that the moles leave behind, but on occasion she will dig where there are no visual signs of activity. However, when I look closely, there is in fact a hidden tunnel where she was digging.

I presume she is digging for an animal that has tunnel routes under the tile. Dogs have an incredibly amazing ability to find things by scent, some breeds more than others.

Since it’s unrealistic for you to pull up the tiles to find out what she is after, you might go digging around in the garden to see if there are rodent tunnels there.